# Convert String To Integer And Vice-Versa

Tags: string, integer, nsbasic

I'm building a calculator application, and I have a Form, with a `TextBox` called `txtVisor`, that has the property `NumbersOnly = true`. I want to get the content of it(that I already know: `txtVisor.Text`) and convert it into a `Integer`, to do multiply it by 12, then convert the result into a `String` to set the `txtVisor.Text` as the result of the operation. How could I do this?

*PS: I'm using NSBasic 7.0*

Comment: NSBAsic 7.0? Why are you using this language?

Comment: @Hamish: Because I'm developing for Windows CE and for Palm OS.

Answer (score 0):

txtVisor.Text = cstr( cint(txtVisor.Text)*12 )

The current version is NS Basic/CE 8, which will make your life much easier when it comes time to deploy your app.